# scanf trick to get parsing correct

Tags: c

I'm parsing a line from a configuration file. It has the following format:

```
100px@white
```

I'm using sscanf for parsing.

```
 rcScanf = sscanf( paramPosition , "%d%2s", &(item->position) , positionFormat );
```

This works well because I can check if `scanf` were able to make 2 matches and I can `strcmp` position Format to check if it is "px" as I'm expecting. The problem is that I would like `scanf` to get exactly "px", not "pxxxxx" or something else. What is the trick in the format string (if there is one) that enables this?

Thank you.

Comment: Ensure `positionFormat` is terminated with `'\0'` after scanning the input.

Comment: I do a memset in it before doing anything. But thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **2x** %n:

```
int b=0,e=0,r,p;

r = sscanf( "100px@white", "%d%npx@%n", &p, &b, &e );

if( r==1 && e-b==3 )
  puts("success");
```

Comment: I didn't test it this way. Will it work if parameter line continues? The actual format is like an array of the example I send. Like this:100px@white;200px@black;500px@gray

Comment: split your whole-string at ';' with eg. strsep, and you can use the solution above

Comment: Note: `r` is not needed but looks nice.  Could simplify to `if (e-b == 3)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `"%n"`

```
int n = 0;
sscanf(paramPosition, "%dpx%n", &(item->position), &n);
if (n && paramPosition[n] == '@') Success();
```